# String of numbers can't start with zero. Other Solutions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have a string that only contains numbers, but the string can not start with a zero.

The first thing I cam up with was this:

```js
let myNumber = "0052";
myNumber = myNumber.split('');
for (let i = 0; i < myNumber.length; i++) {
    if (myNumber[i] == '0') {
        myNumber.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
console.log(myNumber);
console.log('result:', myNumber.join(''));
```

Everything works fine like that.

I thought there might be an other way without using a classical for-loop.
My attempt with a for-of loop failed. As soon as I remove the first entry of my array, the index of the loop does not reset, so it skips the second **zero** in my array. Here is the code for that:

```js
let myNumber = "0052";
myNumber = myNumber.split('');
for (let n of myNumber) {
    if (n == '0') {
        myNumber.shift();
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
console.log(myNumber);
console.log('result:', myNumber.join(''));
```

What other solutions to this problem are there? Is there a more performant solution?

Comment: So your spurce code works but you want to explore other methods/solutions? If so then your question is in the wrong place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're probably looking for is `parseInt` function.

```js
const result = parseInt("0052", 10).toString();
console.log(result);
```

I also added `toString()` to convert number to a string. `parseInt` also accepts second argument - the radix. [Read more about parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseInt)

Comment: This is probably the straightforward solution :-)

Comment: @Ele yes I think so. Since i'm not working with floats. Tomasz Thanks for your answer, Sometimes I just think way to far out of the box

Comment: Sometimes the solution may be easier than we think! :) Take a look at @Ele 's answer as thinking with regex is also good in many situations

Comment: Bad idea even with specifying radix as 10? Good point though!

Answer (score 5):

Regexp: `/^[0]+/`

```js
let myNumber = "0000000520";
console.log(myNumber.replace(/^[0]+/, ''))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use 
`parseInt('0052') = 52`

or

`parseFloat('0052.29') = 52.29` if your number is float type:

Comment: thanks for your answer, but @Tomasz already used parseInt

Answer (score 0):

I just have different and simpler approach than yours :)

```
while(myNumber.length){
  if(myNumber.charAt(0) == '0')
    myNumber = myNumber.substring(1, myNumber.length);
}
```

DEMO : https://jsbin.com/falejuruwu/1/edit?js,console

Comment: simpler: `while(myNumber.charAt(0) == '0') myNumber = myNumber.slice(1);`

Comment: @doodlemeister yours better :) I forgot about slice